# How to rewrite a function body in Idris so that the type corresponds to the function signature and the whole thing compiles

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I would like for this to compile:

```
foo: Vect n String -> Vect n String
foo {n} xs = take n xs
```

This fails to compile because the compiler cannot unify `n` with `n + m`. I understand that this is because of the signature of `take` for Vect's but I cannot figure out how to go about showing the compiler that they can be unified if `m = 0`.

Comment: where does ```m``` is defined ?

Comment: `m` is a type variable from `Vector.take`

Comment: What is the function intended to do? The type indicates that the length of the output list (n) is the same as the length of the input (n), and the only way to achieve that is for the output to *be* the input...

The implementation, on the other hand, suggests that you want the length of the output to be exactly n, where that is not necessarily the length of the input.

Comment: @EdwinBrady But n is the length of the input. Does the type declaration not say so or are all of the n's in the above code not all one and the same?

Comment: @UndercoverAgent Yes, they are - the thing that confused me here was what the `take` was intended for, since it's always going to result in `xs`. Or is this part of something larger? I have a more concise solution anyway, which I'll give as a proper answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @edwin yes, this is a simplification of a real problem of compiling some code that actually does something useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to add to the previous answer, one other possibility is to do the rewrite inline using the existing `plusZeroRightNeutral` lemma from the library:

```
foo: Vect n String -> Vect n String
foo {n} xs = let xs' : Vect (n + 0) String
                     = rewrite (plusZeroRightNeutral n) in xs in
                 take n xs'
```

The difficulty Idris is having in unification is because it is unwilling to infer the `m` in the application of take:

```
take : (n : Nat) -> Vect (n + m) a -> Vect n a
```

You've given it a `Vect n String` where it wanted a `Vect (n + m) a` - it has happily unified the `a` with the `String`, because `Vect` is a type constructor, but is unwilling to unify `n` with `n + m` because, in general, it can't invert functions. You and I can tell that `m` has to be zero, but Idris is not so clever.

Answer (score 3):

Idris can't unify `n` with `n + m` because it does not know that `n = n + 0`. You need to help him by manually proving that.

First of all, why it needs this proof. The reason is that `take` expects `Vect (n+m) a`:

```
Idris> :t Vect.take
Prelude.Vect.take : (n : Nat) -> Vect (n + m) a -> Vect n a
```

So, this will typecheck

```
foo: Vect (n + 0) String -> Vect n String
foo {n} xs = take n xs
```

You need a way to convert `Vect n a` to `Vect (n + 0) a`:

```
addNothing : {n : Nat} -> {a : Type} -> Vect n a -> Vect (n+Z) a
```

It is possible with `replace` function:

```
Idris> :t replace
replace : (x = y) -> P x -> P y
```

But now you need a proof that `n = n + 0`. Here it is (with the rest of the code):

```
plusAddZero : (n : Nat) -> n = n + 0
plusAddZero = proof
  intros
  rewrite (plusCommutative n 0)
  trivial

addNothing : {n : Nat} -> {a : Type} -> Vect n a -> Vect (n + 0) a
addNothing {n} {a} = replace {P = \m => Vect m a} (plusAddZero n)

foo : Vect n String -> Vect n String
foo {n} xs = Vect.take n (addNothing xs)
```

Seems like too much for such a simple function. Hope someone will show more concise solution.

Comment: At that point, I'd almost rather implement the function as: `foo {n} xs = Vect.take n ([] ++ xs)`

Comment: I am going to upvote this answer because it has valuable insight into Idris, but wait a bit to accept it as the answer in the hopes that there is a better way in Idris.

Comment: `Vect.take n (xs ++ [])` is very nice. Don't hesitate to post it as an  answer.